# Using AJAX to execute a python script that takes a picture (raspberry pi)

Tags: python, ajax, django, dynamic, raspberry-pi

I am working on a project for which I need to build a web interface that will allow interaction with a Raspberry Pi camera. I am using Django and python for the back end. I want to be able to press a button on the web interface that will execute a python script to take a picture with the pi camera. I am thinking I need to use AJAX to complete this, but I don't really understand how I would set this up. I am relatively new to Django itself.

Comment: You need a Python library that allows you to connect to the camera and take a picture. Then you need to write a Django view that takes the picture (using this library) and returns it's path as JSON, associate a Django URL to this view, and call this URL from your Javascript with an Ajax request. I think this question is too broad though. Please try to narrow it.

Comment: I have the python code written to take the picture complete. The part I don't understand is how to have the web page send the request to execute the python script. I don't know what the view.py or Ajax request code is supposed to look like. Handling the request itself is where I get lost.

Answer (score 0):

So let's assume you have a Python function that takes a picture with the camera and returns the path to the file.

```
from my_module import take_pic

my_pic = take_pic()
print(my_pic)  # '/path/to/the/picture'
```

You're saying you don't know what the `views.py` should look like so I'll assume that you don't have any Django code ready. To create a Django project, install Django and use `django-admin startproject NAME`.

So what you need is a Django view and it's associated URL. Let's begin with the URL:

```
# urls.py
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^take_pic/', views.take_picture, name='take_pic'),
]
```

Now, create the `views.py` module in the same folder that `urls.py` is in.

```
# views.py
from django.http import JsonResponse

from my_module import take_pic


def take_picture(request):
    my_pic = take_pic()
    return JsonResponse({'path': my_pic})
```

Finally in your Javascript code (most probably in an Django HTML template, rendered with another view, but I'll leave that as an exercise):

```
// this example uses JQuery, but you can find plain Javascript examples on the net

<button id="my-button"></button>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<script>

  $(document).ready(function () {

    $('my-button').click(function() {

      // url name here is what you wrote in urls.py
      $.getJSON('{% url "take_pic" %}', function (data) {

        var picture_path = data.path;
        // add an HTML <img> tag where you need it, using the picture path
        // note that your view might need to return a relative path, not absolute
      });

    });

  });

</script>
```

I think this is a good place to start!

Comment: Thanks Pawamoy, this was very helpful. I posted my code above (I'm still new to Stackoverflow I hope this was the right way to do this). I am hoping you can help me clarify my issue?

Comment: Glad it helped! StackOverflow is not meant to "discuss" (it's not like a forum), so you should not have added an "answer" since it's technically **not** an answer. But this is fine because we will fix your last issue, and you will be able to edit your answer and mark it as accepted later, **unless other issues appear**, and in that case it would be better to remove the answer until you fix them all. In short, post an answer once and only **once** you got the solution! :)